# Combine ReliefPlot with other geographic shapes, like administrative boundaries

Tags: plotting, geography

How can I combine a `ReliefPlot` with other geographic shapes? Since the `ReliefPlot` is just a plain array of values, it is not clear to me how to project it and combine it with other geographic shapes, like administrative boundaries.

For example, I can generate a `ReliefPlot` of Maine like this:

```
ReliefPlot[
 GeoElevationData[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", "Maine"]], 
 DataReversed -> True]
```

but how would I put, for example, an outline of the state of Maine on it or combine it with the locations of cities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `GeoGraphics` with `GeoStyling`.

```
GeoGraphics[{
  GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], 
  Polygon[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Maine", "UnitedStates"}]]}]
```

[image: map]